# intro.js show and hide data-hint

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

I want to have a button that can turn on and off the 'hints' function in intro.js.

I have a working version to show and then hide but the show only works once. How can I get it to work repeatedly? This functionality works for the standard data-intro but not for data-hint.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 id='step1'>Hints</h1>
    <p class="lead">Adding hints using JSON + callbacks</p>
    <a id='step2' class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);">Add hints</a>
</div>

function addHints(){
    intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        hints: [
          {
            element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
            hint: "This is a tooltip.",
            hintPosition: 'top-middle'
          },
          {
            element: '#step2',
            hint: 'More features, more fun.',
            position: 'left'
          },
          {
            element: '#step4',
            hint: "<b>Another</b> step.",
            hintPosition: 'top-middle'
          }
        ]
      });
      intro.onhintsadded(function() {
          console.log('all hints added');
      });
      intro.onhintclick(function(hintElement, item, stepId) {
          console.log('hint clicked', hintElement, item, stepId);
      });
      intro.onhintclose(function (stepId) {
          console.log('hint closed', stepId);
      });
      intro.addHints();
  }
 $(function() {
    $('#step2').click(function(){
        if ( $('#step2').hasClass('clicked') ) {
            introJs().hideHints();
            $('#step2').removeClass('clicked');
        } else {
            addHints();
            $('#step2').addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `hideHints` intro.js API method just remove the div block of intro.js from DOM:

```
var introDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("introjs-hints")[0];
introDiv.parentNode.removeChild(introDiv);
```

(You can do the same thing with jQuery if you want to).

When the div is removed from DOM, just initialize hints once again as you do with your `addHints` method when you want to show hints and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the div block with javascript. You can use .removeHints()

This function is part of intro.js, but is not included in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit hacky, but this works for me...

First, put your hints into their own variable:

```
hints = [{...}, ...]
```

then, reset your hints in the intro options

```
intro.onhintclose(function(stepId) { 
  if (document.querySelectorAll('.introjs-hidehint').length === hints.length) {
    intro.setOptions({hints: hints}) 
  } 
})
```

The hidden hints are given a class of introjs-hidehint, and document.querySelectorAll will return all of them in an array. Once that array is the same size as your hints array, reset your hints in your intro options and that will reset all your hints so you can show them all again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete example that also allows:

(a) toggling hints on/off by clicking a button (located on a nav bar so used across multiple pages).

(b) once all hints have been clicked, the hints div gets removed so that clicking show hints button will again actually...show hints...

(c) allow you to store hints for multiple pages in a single json object array (re: nav bar).

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
var introJs = require('intro.js');

* ===========================================================================
*       define onclick of hints button
* =========================================================================*/
jquery('#hints_button').on('click', function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('introjs-hints').length == 0){
        addSomeHints();
    }
    else {
        destroyHints();
    };
});

/* ===========================================================================
 *      Add hints using the IntroJS library
 * =========================================================================*/

/* define hints */
var theHints = [
{
        element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
        hint: "This is a tooltip.",
        hintPosition: 'top-middle'
      },
      {
        element: '#step2',
        hint: 'More features, more fun.',
        hintPosition: 'left'
      },
      {
        element: '#step4',
        hint: "<b>Another</b> step.",
        hintPosition: 'top-middle'
      }
];

/* generate hints with introjs */
function addSomeHints() {
    intro = introJs();

    intro.setOptions({
        hints: theHints
    });

    intro.onhintclose(function (stepId) {
        var remaining_hints = all_hints - document.getElementsByClassName("introjs-hidehint").length;
        if (remaining_hints == 0) {
            destroyHints();
        };
    });

    /* add hints */
    intro.addHints();

    /* store number of hints created */
    var all_hints = document.getElementsByClassName('introjs-hint').length;

};

/* remove hints div */
function destroyHints() {
    var hintsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("introjs-hints")[0]
    hintsDiv.parentNode.removeChild(hintsDiv);
};
```

... hopefully this saves someone the 20 minutes it took me to piece together the answers and adapt it for what seems like a super common use case.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same for a dashboard and the solution was to place the following code in the styles:

```
.introjs-hidehint {
     display: block !important;
}
```